# Why does my basic css layout render incorrectly in internet explorer?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html

So I am experimenting with pure css layouts, and immediately I have become stuck.  I have the following html and css:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Layout</title>
        <link type="text/css" href="site.css" rel="stylesheet" >
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <a href="#" id="logo">My Site</a>

            <div id="search-area">
                <form>
                    <input type="text" id="search-box" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="sidebar">
            Account Name <br>
            <a href="#">Edit My Account</a>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>

#header {
    background-color: #151B54;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
}

#logo {
    position: relative;
    left: 10px;
    color: white;
    font-size: x-large;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 3px;
}

#search-area {
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
    margin-top: 3px;
}

#sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    border-right: double;
}
```

When I view this in Chrome I get the rendering that I was expecting:

[image]

However, in IE I get the following:

[image]

Notice how there is a massive blank area to the left of the sidebar.  Why is that showing in IE?

Comment: Which version of IE is affected?

Comment: always use css resets to remain consistent in most browsers.

Comment: @Knu IE8 (only version I have installed)

Comment: Funny thing is that it renders here fine on IE7/8 like as on Chrome screen, but renders on IE9 exactly as on your IE screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get the same problem in Safari and for the same reason: you're not clearing your floats in `#header` and `#header` isn't quite tall enough to contain all of its floated children.

If you increase the height of the header to 31px, you should (but maybe not) get the desired layout. A better approach is you add `overflow: hidden` as a clear fix, that will make all of the children of `#header` fully contained with `#header` and that will stop them from interfering with the layout of the next piece:

```
#header {
    background-color: #151B54;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/EUmyN/

A rule of thumb with floated elements is to always make sure they're cleared either with `overflow: hidden` on their container or, if necessary, with an explicit `<div style="clear: both;"></div>` at the bottom of the container.

Also, while we're here, you rarely need `width: 100%` on a block element such as a `<div>`. If you're positioning it or floating then maybe you'll need something like that but not for a plain `<div>`; block elements are full width by default.

Comment: overflow: hidden did the trick.  Thanks for the good explanation :)

Answer (score -1):

Try clearing your online cache. Oftentimes the css file is cached and using an older version causing this type of behavior.

May not be the problem, but the first action you should take when trying to troubleshoot unexpected results on style.

Comment: Nope doesn't seem to be a caching issue.